# «Водолазы начали торопиться, понимая, что изотопы разрушали их тела». Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, сложное-предложение, деепричастия

Правильно ли стоит указанная запятая в предложении?

```
Водолазы начали торопиться, понимая(,) что изотопы разрушали их тела.
```

Мне интересно, правильно ли поставлена запятая, потому что по правилу это должно быть одиночное деепричастие. Но я в этом не совсем не уверен.

Answer (score 2):

Пунктуация в Вашем предложении правильная.
*Понимая* — это действительно одиночное деепричастие, которое обособляется [**на общих основаниях**](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0/) (одиночные деепричастия выделяются запятыми независимо от места в предложении, за исключением тех, которые тесно связаны со сказуемым).
За деепричастием следует придаточное предложение (понимая *что?*).
Единственное, что бы я сделала, — поменяла время глагола "разрушать" (прошедшее на настоящее).

**Водолазы начали торопиться, понимая, что изотопы разрушают их тела.**

*Он **торопился** закончить свой труд, **понимая, что** может быть арестован в любой момент* ([В. И. Сталин. От отца не отрекаюсь!](https://books.google.ee/books?id=P0cYDAAAQBAJ&pg=PT4&lpg=PT4&dq=%D0%9E%D0%BD%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4,%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F,%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82.&source=bl&ots=7-qOTPDehu&sig=ACfU3U3j8pm6nkEHjtFL0Abyip_2AgD1nw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjFytrjktnnAhVBAxAIHYF3CrUQ6AEwAHoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%9E%D0%BD%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B4%2C%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%8F%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82.&f=false)).
*Михеев **торопился, понимая, что** Ерожин его ждет и злится* (А. Анисимов).

P. S. Есть случаи, когда [деепричастие не выделяется запятыми](http://raal100.narod.ru/index/0-162).